# Curl command in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, curl, token

I am using Python3.9.
I have below curl command :

```
curl -x proxy1.req:8080 --location --request POST 'https://auth.trst.com/2.0' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'ct_id=33d3e1-4988-9a08-e7773634ba67' \
--data-urlencode 'ct_sec=56GgtoQA8.WIH9nFM3Eh3sT~cwH' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=https://auth.trst.com/settlement/.default' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

Which is returning response as below:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1355  100  1163  100   192   1340    221 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1566{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrNHh5b2pORnVtMWtsMll0djhkbE5QNC1jNTdkTzZRR1RWQndhTmsiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV9SRSIsInNjcCI6ImRlZmF1bHQiLCJhenBhY3IiOiIxIiwic3ViIjoiZWI3OTU1OTktMzZhMy00SqQe5v9xuYRSfOb_gMgpt7Kez8B0dsnJ_SmT17Hbd7dXLS5p5xTva2iteHp80E2PBYy8jIdtDFcyyC3JSb_d1jzeRrtn5ILlR9eMiMMQa5k65rEXuWYlDpCCtyNS0vcbzA6raxuT1ux8-riCRnGe_TX-VP7FTzPxE7bN1N6N60Ahm7cvzmdDjtKgga0ltybKT2LKtT_hwIwYnuPOdYCGy5jYQ78kaZH86PVSXBuzHw","token_type":"Bearer","not_before":1696859605,"expires_in":3600,"expires_on":1696863205,"resource":"6f4cd1ba-556d-4cb3-ab69-12eac3243387"}
```

I want to to execute this `curl` command in `Python` and store the token value in variable so that I can use this variable for further logic in `Python` but not sure how to execute this `curl` command in `Python`.

Comment: curl is an HTTP client intended to used as CLI.  If you want to use the same functionality In python use libraries like `requests`.

Comment: do you mean i have to rewrite the curl logic in python using modules ?

Comment: maybe you can consider of `subprocess`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: You can execute external commands in python using `subprocess`. However using libraries like requests has it's own benefits(speed/no need to manually parse the reponse etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@AbdulNiyasPM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6699447/abdul-niyas-p-m) said:

> curl is an HTTP client intended to used as CLI. If you want to use the same functionality In python use libraries like requests.

So, you can do it this way:

```py
import requests

# Request URL
url = 'https://auth.trst.com/2.0'

# Headers
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

# Payload
payload = {
    'ct_id': '33d3e1-4988-9a08-e7773634ba67',
    'ct_sec': '56GgtoQA8.WIH9nFM3Eh3sT~cwH',
    'scope': 'https://auth.trst.com/settlement/.default',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
}

# Proxy URL
proxy_url = 'http://proxy1.baag:8080'

# Make the request with the proxy
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, proxies={'http': proxy_url, 'https': proxy_url})

# Check if the request was successful (HTTP code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the JSON response to get the access token
    response_data = response.json()
    access_token = response_data.get('access_token')
    
    # TODO: Use the access token as needed
else:
    # TODO: Handle the error
```

Comment: i just tried and added print(response) at last but it did not print token value and return as   <Response [200]>

Comment: You should use `response.text`, I added it to the answer.

Comment: thanks its working now but its printing complete response now same like which i mentioned in question using curl. If i just wanted to store the value of access_token in variable will it be not possible ? Because i want to use this variable value in further logic in this code.

Comment: Got it, I've improved the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `requests` library to do it directly without curl:

```
import requests

url = "https://auth.trst.com/2.0"

headers = {"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

data = {"ct_id": "33d3e1-4988-9a08-e7773634ba67",
        "ct_sec": "56GgtoQA8.WIH9nFM3Eh3sT~cwH",
        "scope": "https://auth.trst.com/settlement/.default",
        "grant_type": "client_credentials"}

proxies = { "https" : "proxy1.baag:8080" }

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data proxies=proxies)
```

If the requests library is not already installed, get it with `pip`:

```
python -m pip install requests
```